# ImportError: partition_docx is not available using Langchain on HuggingFace

Tags: python, importerror, langchain, huggingface

I am using the DirectoryLoader with Langchain on HuggingFace (Gradio SDK) like so from my folder named "data":

```
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader  
  
loader = DirectoryLoader('./data/')  
raw_documents = loader.load()
```

but get the following error:

*ImportError: partition_docx is not available. Install the docx dependencies with pip install "unstructured[docx]"*

Does anyone have any insight as to why this error is being given? Nothing pops up for me on a web search for this error.

Thanks in advance! Apologies if more context is needed, just getting into python and I am very novice.

Comment: As error suggests,  install `pip install "unstructured[docx]"`

Comment: @simpleApp This is hosted on HuggingFace. Maybe I'm missing something being so new to this, but my understanding is that all these are already on HuggingFace's library and only need to be imported. Do you use HuggingFace? Is there a way I can do this there that I'm not aware of? Pretty confused.

Comment: (I already have this installed on my Mac as well.)

Comment: Need more info. Are you coding this on your mac or building code on huggingface space or so?

Comment: I am building this on my HuggingFace space! :) Not locally on my mac.

Comment: thanks for getting me back on track :) lol and is Streamlit space ?

Comment: It is a Gradio space!

Comment: you need to manage the dependencies through the requirements.txt file. so create a `requirements.txt`file and add the modules you need. refer this https://huggingface.co/spaces/Simpleapp/note/tree/main

Comment: Oh! Adding `unstructured[docx]` to my  `requirements.txt` file did the trick! Thanks so much! If you post that as a question, I'll be happy to accept it!

Comment: Wow!! Let me put some detail which will help the future readers.

Comment: (Whoops, meant to say post it as an **Answer** here :) )

Comment: here goes the answer! thanks for the motivation to learn hugging face spaces :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Op Leanna created the Gradio space and then noticed the import error. so here are all the details.

For debugging, create Gradio space
In Hugging Face,

1. Create Gradio space
   [image]

2. To manage dependencies, create `requirements.txt` and add the modules that are needed:

```
langchain
unstructured
unstructured[docx]
```

Files can be reviewed at : [SimpleappGradio](https://huggingface.co/spaces/Simpleapp/note/tree/main)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install unstructured, assuming that you have already installed other  dependecies like libreoffice..

```
pip install unstructured
```